# Package Arules in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, rpy2, arules

I am using arules in Python. I executed the below code to generate all associations. I want to know how can i convert the output of arules to some data-structure in Python. The output if of type **'rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4'**.
--below is the code---

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
arules = importr("arules")
od = OrderedDict()
od["supp"] = 0.0005
od["conf"] = 0.7
od["target"] = 'rules'
df = pd.DataFrame (
    [
        ['1','1', '1'],
        ['1', '0','0'],
        ['1', '1', '1'],
        ['1', '0', '0'],
        ['1', '1', '1'],
        ['1', '0', '1'],
        ['1', '1', '1'],
        ['0', '0', '1'],
        ['0', '1', '1'],
        ['1', '0', '1'],
    ],
    columns=list ('ABC')) 
result = ListVector(od)
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('category')
df['C'] = df['C'].astype('category')
my_rules = arules.apriori(df, parameter=result)
print("herererererere")
print(type(my_rules))
print("rules")
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: library('arules')           
a= c( '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '0'   ) 
b= c( '1' , '0' , '1' , '0' , '1' , '0' , '1' , '0' , '1' , '0'   )
c= c( '1' , '0' , '1' , '0' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1'   )
pd =  data.frame(a,b, c  , stringsAsFactors = TRUE) 
rules = apriori( pd )
r = as(rules , "data.frame")

Comment: Running the above code in R , i get the below output. How can i convert the output in python to below format ? 
output     
{a=0,b=0} => {c=1}     0.1      1.000 1.2500000     1
{a=0,c=1} => {b=0}     0.1      1.000 2.0000000     1
 {b=0,c=0} => {a=1}     0.2      1.000 1.1111111     2
 {a=1,c=0} => {b=0}     0.2      1.000 2.0000000     2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimalist example of how to do this:

```
# prepare the data as a dataframe with boolean values
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame (
    [
        [True,True, True],
        [True, False,False],
        [True, True, True],
        [True, False, False],
        [True, True, True],
        [True, False, True],
        [True, True, True],
        [False, False, True],
        [False, True, True],
        [True, False, True],
    ],
    columns=list ('ABC')) 

# set up rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
arules = importr("arules")

# run apriori
itsets = arules.apriori(df, 
   parameter = ro.ListVector({"supp": 0.1, "target": "frequent itemsets"}))

# get itemsets as a dataframe
print(arules.DATAFRAME(itsets))

# get quality as a dataframe
print(itsets.slots["quality"])

# get itemsets as a matrix
itemset_as_matrix = ro.r('function(x) as(items(x), "matrix")')
itemset_as_matrix(itsets)
```